# C++ custom datatype created with using keyword

Tags: c++, using

Working through a new C++ book and I've noticed the author using the "using" keyword to create custom, almost class-object style, datatypes. Style 1 is an example from the book. Style 2 is the code I would typically write.

Is that what's happening here? Would anyone be able to correct me or go into greater detail?

Style 1:

`using MessageContainer = std::vector<std::string>;`

`class Textbox {private: MessageContainer m_messages;`

Style 2:

`class Textbox {private: std::vector<std::string> m_messages;`

Comment: it's type alias in c++, `MessageContainer` is same as `std::vector<std::string>` similar to `typedef`

Comment: Search for "type alias"; in C or if you want to use the less readable variant in C++, `typedef` would direct you to an alternative way of achieving an effect like this... https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Comment: These kinds of aliases are used to help convey the *semantics* of the type.  They also can be a single place to change them, for example switching out from a `vector` to `list` as the container.  The extra level of aliasing indirection can be annoying, but a good IDE can help immensely at demystifying the aliases.